# How do I install and configure Grub to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I have a Lenovo v570 and need to run Linux. The steps I took are:

1. Delete the small Lenovo partition.
2. Defragment the hard disk drive
3. Shrink the C: boot primary partition
4. Download Ubuntu LTS
5. Burn Ubuntu to dvd
6. Restart computer loading Ubuntu from dvd
7. Installing Ubuntu in a partition in the saved space

The system forced a shutdown and I couldn't boot Ubuntu from the new partition.

1. Boot Ubuntu from dvd with the Try Ubuntu option.
2. Open the terminal
3. Followed the instructions for [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)
4. Noticed that Grub (whatever that does) isn't installed.
5. Told to copy and paste the system information and ask for help.

The link to the system information is http://paste.ubuntu.com/6558233/

How do I configure the system to boot either Ubuntu or Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a newer system that is UEFI with CSM.
UEFI Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which emulates a BIOS mode

But your Windows is installed in BIOS boot mode and then drive has to be MBR. So if you boot in UEFI mode Ubuntu will not install correctly.
UEFI has to have gpt partitioned drives.
BIOS has to have MBR(msdos) partitioned drives.

You need to make sure you boot Ubuntu installer or Boot-Repair in BIOS boot mode not UEFI boot mode. They are not compatible and once you start booting in one mode you cannot switch.

If you boot Boot-Repair in BIOS mode from UEFI/BIOS menu with CSM/Legacy/BIOS boot on, or UEFI off, then Boot-Repair should be able to help you chroot into your system and install grub-pc which is for BIOS boot.

Comment: I downloaded and created a Boot Repair disk following the first link on the 1st options [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). I ran boot repair again and it resolved the chroot issues and automatically installed drub-pc. All happy now. Thanks.